# How to find which database technology is used by a website.

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to find the database technology using for a website. 
eg. www.example.com/

i want to know the database technology such as mysql or oracle  of a example.com

Comment: Do you want to become hacker?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Not like that . i just want to analysis about a website what are the technologies they are using like frameworks , cms , database etc.

Comment: frameworks , cms can be understood by observation but about database it needs to be internal contacts with website builder organization. :P Or you needs to have high imagination power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not. A lot of the bigger sites/companies publish the technology they use, but if you are wanting to know the database backend of some random site, you can't

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Unless the coder handled db exception properly !!!